# Elimitate ssh login delay without touching sshd

Tags: linux, ssh, dns

Whenever I login to a certain server using SSH I get a very long delay before a prompt appears. Everything I looked up on this issue says that it's a DNS issue and that I should disable reverse DNS lookups on the server.

But, the remote server is a shared webhosting server. I e-mailed the sysadmins but they say they have no DNS issue and that they won't change the server configuration. So, how can I fix this issue from my side (client side)? I have a static IP address and a hostname that points to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue is with the remote server's DNS settings. Because it's a shared server, looking up the IP address of the server does not result in the correct hostname. Adding the address of the server to my local /etc/hosts fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't - you can't disable the DNS lookup from the client side alone.

Comment: I know. But what can I do to make the DNS lookup succeed instead? That should eliminate the delay as well. Like I said, I have a static IP and a valid hostname on the client side.

Comment: You will need to set up both forward hostname->ip and reverse (ip->hostname) lookups for your IP and hostname, usually people pay no attention to the latter, which is usually where the delay related problems originate.

Comment: @cbz: Theoretically, the lookup should succeed instantly *even if it results in a NXDOMAIN rather than a name/address*; if it times out, you have a different problem.

Comment: I'm not sure that's entirely correct - it won't cache NXDOMAIN results - so will do a hierarchical search each time if it never finds a valid response.

Comment: My hostname is 525fdd52.xs4all.nl and both forward and reverse IP work (I think, please check). So, how do I tell the remote sshd server *my* hostname? Is that in the ssh pubkey?

Comment: Nevermind. I just found out that the cause is not my (client) hostname/IP but the server's. Because it's a shared server, looking up the IP address of the server does not result in the correct hostname. Adding the address of the server to my local /etc/hosts fixed the issue.